# DNS and traceroute

Tags: dns

[image]

[image]

some other big slovenian site has only 14 traceroutes

[image]

is my traceroute big. I have dns for domains at zoneedit or freedns.afraid.org. Is this bad? Must i use slovenian dns servers? I do not want slow DNS resolving.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traceroute is to your server (for dostavahrane.si), not to the DNS for your server name; in any case, it is ok.  This traceroute has nothing to do with your the time to get to  your DNS, but that's generally not something to worry about.  The time needed for DNS is usually fine as long as the DNS server itself is good.  The country it is located in doesn't matter.

Comment: Hi. Thx for answer.